# Bitnami Redmine Windows Installer Upgrade to 3.3.1

Tags: redmine, bitnami

Most of the documentation examples are for Linux:
https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/redmine/#how-to-upgrade-redmine

I would like to see one for the Windows Server variety. Trying to upgrade 3.2.2 to 3.3.1. Client wants to keep it on local Windows only. No cloud.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bitnami Developer here. Thanks for your comment, we will update soon the documentation of bitnami to add more guides of windows. 
I have been able to migrate to redmine 3.2.2 to 3.3.1, these are the steps you have to follow:

- Go to the `manager-windows` (`C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.2.2-0\manager-windows.exe`) and stop all the services. Then start again mysql. You should have something like this:
  [manager-windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGWIY.png)
- Do a dump of your mysql database. You can use the `use-redmine` console to do this (`C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.2.2-0\use_redmine.exe`) and execute the following:

`mysqldump -u root -p --databases bitnami_redmine > backup.sql`

- Save that backup and download the last version of redmine stack installer (3.3.1-0): [Bitnami redmine installers](https://bitnami.com/stack/redmine/installer)
- Install it in your machine and open the `manager-windows` (`C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.3.1-0\manager-windows.exe`). Stop all services and start again the mysql service to restore the backup.
- Start the `use_redmine` console(`C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.3.1-0\use_redmine.exe`)
- Execute the following in the `use_redmine` console:

  ```
  mysql -u root -p 
  Password: ****
  mysql> drop database bitnami_redmine;
  mysql> create database bitnami_redmine;
  mysql> grant all privileges on bitnami_redmine.* to 'bn_redmine'@'localhost' identified by 'DATABASE_PASSWORD';
  ```
- Restore the new database:

  ```
  `mysql -u root -p bitnami_redmine < /path/to/your/backup.sql`
  ```
- Edit the Redmine configuration file to update the database user password (the same that you set previously) at

  `C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.3.1-0\apps\redmine\htdocs\config\database.yml`:

  ```
  production:
    adapter: mysql2
    database: bitnami_redmine
    host: localhost
    username: bn_redmine
    password: "DATABASE_PASSWORD"
    encoding: utf8
  ```
- In the `use_redmine` console migrate the database to the latest version:

  ```
  bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
  ```
- After this, you should be able to start all the services again in the `C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.3.1-0\manager-windows.exe` and log in in the application as always.

Comment: I got an error on the db:migrate, but was resolved by changing the directory: "cd C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.3.3-0\apps\redmine\htdocs".  Thanks to Carlos @ https://community.bitnami.com/t/unable-to-restore-redmine-database-on-new-win-server-machine/45528/9

Comment: Also a reminder to copy your plugins and files folder over to your new installation.

Comment: To run the use_redmine console, you call "use_redmine.bat", not "use_redmine.exe".